# How to edit makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile, make

I want to add -std=c99 flag to make command but I have no idea how to do it. Where is related file located?

@Andrejs Cainikovs But I have not found related file or files yet.

Comment: Makefile usually is placed in project top folder. However, if the project has multiple source file folders, there *might* be more than one Makefile. Find them: `find -name Makefile`.

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs 
it returned nothing hrn@hrn-vaio:~$ find -name make
hrn@hrn-vaio:~$

Comment: This is not the same command.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: @david6 I have done all possibilities even so I could not find anything

Comment: No. You've executed `find -name make` instead of `find -name Makefile`. Correct command should find you all makefiles within your project, assuming you are located at it's top folder. You need to specify `CFLAGS=-std=c99` only for your top Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a Makefile:

```
$ CFLAGS="-std=c99" make
```

Adding following to your Makefile will also work:

> CFLAGS=-std=c99

Or, if using configure:

```
$ CFLAGS="-std=c99" ./configure
```

Comment: It did not work

OUTPUT
[code]
hrn@hrn-vaio:~/c$ CFLAGS=-std=c99
hrn@hrn-vaio:~/c$ make hrn
cc     hrn.c   -o hrn
hrn.c: In function ‘main’:
hrn.c:7:2: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
hrn.c:7:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [hrn] Error 1
hrn@hrn-vaio:~/c$

Comment: Sure it will not work, since you have split original command into two parts, and `make` is not aware about `CFLAGS` anymore. Execute the whole command, as I have provided.

Comment: same error

hrn@hrn-vaio:~/c$ CFLAGS="-std=c99" make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
hrn@hrn-vaio:~/c$ make hrn
cc     hrn.c   -o hrn
hrn.c: In function ‘main’:
hrn.c:7:2: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
hrn.c:7:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [hrn] Error 1
hrn@hrn-vaio:~/c$

Comment: `CFLAGS="-std=c99" make hrn`