# how do I modify makefile which is already compiled?

Tags: make, makefile

Let's say I have a makefile which looks like this:

```
all: a_functions.o b_functions.o c_functions.o d_functions.o main.o
     gcc -o all a_functions.o b_functions.o c_functions.o d_functions.o main.o
a_functions.o: a_functions.c
     gcc -c -o a_functions.o a_functions.c
b_functions.o: b_functions.c
     gcc -c -o b_functions.o b_functions.c
c_functions.o: c_functions.c
     gcc -c -o c_functions.o c_functions.c
main.o: main.c
     gcc -c -o main.o main.c
```

I could compile it using command

```
sudo make -f makefile
```

and program works nice if I run

```
./all
```

but how to do if I want to add for example a clean command in makefile?
I added

```
clean:
     rm *.o all
```

at the end of the makefile but my terminal shows

```
-bash: ./clean: No such file or directory
```

when I do ./clean

Of course recompiling makefile doesn't work either. It shows

```
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

when I do `sudo make -f makefile`

I found here [How to edit makefile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147647/how-to-edit-makefile) that you can use

```
$ CFLAGS="-std=c99" make
```

this command in terminal or I can add

> CFLAGS=-std=c99

in my makefile but they still show

> all is up to date

the image is just evidence that modifying did not work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A makefile is never compiled - it's interpreted by the `make` command. When you run

```
make
```

or more explicitly

```
make -f makefile
```

then by default, `make` builds the first *target* in the `makefile` - in this case, that's the `all` target. To build a non-default target, you need to name it on the command line i.e.

```
make clean
```

or

```
make -f makefile clean
```

Note that the `clean` target does not actually build anything, so unlike `./all` there is no program like `./clean` to run afterwards. In fact, you might want to declare the `clean` target as a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: thank you! your answer helped me a lot